# Efficient solution to find the number of unique binary vectors

Tags: algorithm

Suppose that you have a binary vector (each element can 0, 1 or X, which corresponds to either 0 or 1), of length N.

for example, given N = 4:

1001 is a single binary vector
1XX1 denotes four different binary vectors {1001, 1011, 1101, 1111}

Now suppose you have three different descriptions, e.g.

X11X
1XX1
11XX

What would be an efficient solution to find the number of unique binary vectors described by this set of specifications?

Note that a brute force solution becomes impractical when N grows, so listing every possible vector and deleting duplicates is not a viable solution. Also note that we just want to know the number of unique vectors but we don't need to compute their exact value.

Editing with the solution for this example which would be:

X11X  --> 0110 0111 1110 1111

1XX1  --> 1001 1011 1101 1111

11XX  --> 1100 1101 1110 1111

Among these 12 vectors, we only want to count the unique ones, which are 8 e.g.

0110 0111 1110 1111 1001 1011 1101 1100

Comment: What number do you want for the set of descriptions? Do you want to compute them individually and then add their results together?

Comment: In the example above each specification describes 4 different vectors, so in total they would 12 vectors. But there will be duplicates between them. I just want to compute the number of unique vectors generated by the set of specifications (which if I computed correctly by hand they should 8 unique vectors)

Comment: How large can N be?

Comment: there is no explicit constraint on N, it can be big as you want.

Comment: "it can be as big as you want" We're dealing with a #P-complete problem here (worse than NP; instead of just solution existence/nonexistence, we get a count). Unless you feel like scouring the literature for complicated algorithms, you should be more specific.

Comment: What's the solution to that set? I see two entirely different interpretations (OR vs AND).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principlehttp://). You want to know the cardinality of the union of the set. For your example you have:

```
N(X11X || 1XX1 || 11XX) = N(X11X) + N(1XX1) + N(11XX) - 
                          N(X11X && 1XX1) - N(X11X && 11XX) - N(1XX1 && 11XX) +
                          N(X11X && 1XX1 && 11XX)
```

Cardinality of "single" elements are easy to calculate (2^Nx, where Nx is the number of X elements). For the intersection, you compare element by element. If they are different from X and different from each other, you have zero. If they both are equal, you have 1. If you have a X and a number, you have one. If you have X and X you have two. Then you multiply these numbers. An example:

```
N(X11X && 1XX1) = 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 = 1.
```

which correspond to the only common sequence (1111). This can be easily generalized for any N and shouldn't be hard to implement in any language.

Comment: if you have X and X, you should have 2, why 4?

Comment: @ad3angel1s Oh sure, you are correct, gonna edit. Thank you.

Comment: Just to confirm, applying your solution and using 2 for X and X, I get the expected solution for the test set:
12 - (1*1*1*1) - (1*1*2*1) - (1*1*1*2) + (1*1*1*1) = 8

Answer (score 2):

If the number of patterns stays small then you can solve this using an inclusion-exclusion type approach.

The number of binary vectors for each individual pattern is easy to compute: it is just the appropriate power of 2. Now the total number of patterns is just the sum of the binary vectors for each pattern individually, minus the number of binary vectors for the common solutions of each pair of patterns, plus the sum of the number of common solutions for each triplet, and so on.

The common solutions of a set patterns are again the solution for a single pattern: If, at some position, one pattern has a 0 and another has a 1, then there is no common solution. Otherwise we obtain a pattern by placing 0 or 1 at a position if one of the patterns has a 0 or 1 at this position, and an X if all patterns have an X at this position.